# Change the folders in This PC in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

In the This PC folder in Windows 10, there are some folders, in particular Documents, Pictures, Music and Videos, like the ones circled in red in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to replace the Documents, Pictures, Music and Videos folders (circled in red) with the corresponding libraries (circled in green). For example, the Documents folder here has the location C:\Users\dduck\Documents and I would like to replace it with the Documents library which contains C:\Users\dduck\Documents, C:\Users\dduck\OneDrive\Documents and C:\Users\Public\Documents. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can (easily) modify that section of that view, but maybe someone know.  Putting that aside for now, by default when you open Explorer it opens to "Quick Access"; and you can pin your Documents library to that Quick Access screen.  And/or you could also enable showing "Libraries" in the Navigation pane (the one on the left).  Those don't suffice?

Comment: You want to replace the folder with a location,with the same location, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I don't want to replace a folder with a folder with the same location. The location of the folder that is there now is C:\Users\dduck\Documents and I want to replace it with the library that's at C:\Users\dduck\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms. The thing is that a library is a file which when you open it shows simultaneously the content of all the folders that it contains. In this case, the library contains the three folders that I mentioned in my question and one of them happens to already be in the This PC folder.